# Is it possible to drop export some shema without data and the other with data

Tags: oracle, datapump

I have oracle 11G R2 under `RHEL` 6.3 test is the name of the database, the database contain 12 custom schema, sch1,sch2,...,sch12.  is it possible to create database backup using `datapump` method that contain all of the schema with no data except the first three one, the data is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export specific schema using the `SCHEMAS` parameter:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1007509

You can export the definitions of data alone using the `CONTENT` parameter:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL838

Combine the two:
        expdp user/pass SCHEMAS=a,b,c CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY [........]

This will achieve the aim of just doing the schema.  You'll need to do the 3 schema where you want the data as a separate job.

Comment: Thanks I though I could combine the two command without splitting them into two tasks.

Comment: You can by adding QUERY clause to each table in each of schema where you don't want to export data. The where clause you can add is 'where 1=2'.  It is easy if you split them into two (one with data and one metadata_only) but you can choose what you think is best for you.  and if you choose to add QUERY parameter, you will be better off using a parfile

Comment: I considered using that as a method, but I can't see the benefit of doing it in one job.  It makes it complicated and I wouldn't want to be the person who has to maintain it going forward.  If it's two separate jobs, that's at least clear.